# Two different types of marbles in a box.

Tags: combinatorics

Two different types of marbles in a box: blue and red. Each of blue marbles is $19$ grams, and each of red marbles is $17$ grams. The total weights of all marbles are $2017$ grams. How many total number of both marbles are possible?

This is from a timed competition, fastest answers are better. I really don't know where to start with this. I just plugged this into Excel and got $107,109,111,113,115,117$. Any help?

Comment: Note that if you let $x$ be the weight of the blue marbles and $y$ the weight of the red marbles, then the solution to your problem would be obtained by solving the Diophantine equation $19x + 17y = 2017.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a timed competition, I would concentrate on multiples of the $19$ grams. Try to get close to $2017$ and exceed it by an even value. If we can exceed it by, say, $6$, then we can trade $3$ of these blue marbles for red marbles.

So just very quickly:
$1900 + 190 = 2090$ subtract a $19$ to get $2071$. This used $100+10-1 = 109$ blue marbles.

But we are $2071-2017$ over the target, which is $54g$ over the target, so trading $27$ blue marbles for red ones will be the answer.

$109-27 = 82$ blue and $27$ red  (is one possible answer, of many)

Comment: There are six total solutions.

Comment: @JohnDouma I stated above that they are $107,109,111,113,115,117$.

Comment: Now you can trade $17$ blue ones for $19$ red ones and keep the total weight the same.  You can make one trade of red for blue or up to four trades of blue for red, giving the six total solutions.

Comment: Those are the totals and they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by noticing that an average marble weighs $18$ grams.  If all my marbles were average it would take $\frac {2017}{18}=112\frac 1{18}$ marbles.  I can get there with $111$ average marbles and one blue one.  Unfortunately I can't just trade two average for one blue and one red because of the odd number of average ones.  But I can trade $110$ average marbles for $55$ red and $55$ blue ones, giving a solution with $55$ red, $1$ average, and $56$ blue.  If I change $9$ marbles from red to blue I use up the $18$ grams of the average marble, so my first solution is $46$ red, $65$ blue for a total of $111$ marbles.  Now note I can keep the weight the same trading $19$ red marbles for $17$ blue ones and save two marbles.  I can do that twice, going down to $107$ marbles, or three times the other direction going up to $117$ marbles.  There is a solution for any odd number $107$ to $117$, a total of six.